# MLFLOW - Is there a way to override Pytorch Wrapper?

Tags: python, mlflow

I am trying to use pytorch in mlflow. Currently, predict method allows data that is only of pd.DataFrame or np.ndarray type, is there a way to override this and write a custom predict method without writing a completely new loader_module?

The source code for the predict method can be found here -> [pytorch](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/master/mlflow/pytorch/__init__.py#L706-L736)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Also add your code to the question itself, not on an external site.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override the defined loader_module, instead you can use mlflow custom model definition for defining a custom pytorch functionalities within the model:

```
# Define the model class
import mlflow.pyfunc
class CustomPytorchWrapper(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):

    def load_context(self, context):
        # define model loading method 

    def predict(self, context, model_input):
        # define your custom method to predict
```